# Como verificar números dentro de uma String Java

Tags: java, array, for, numeração

Recebi o seguinte exercício na escola e estou com um problema.

> O código identificador de funcionários de uma empresa contém 7
> caracteres, inicia com a sequência de caracteres BR, em seguida
> apresenta um número inteiro entre 0001 e 9999 e finaliza com o
> caractere X.
>
> Exemplos válidos:
>
> - BR0001X
> - BR1236X
> - BR9999X
>
> Exemplos inválidos:
>
> - br0001X
> - BR126X
> - BR99999X
> - BR9999Y
>
> 1. Avalie os métodos da classe String e Integer e identifique quais poderiam ser utilizados para validar todos os critérios do código identificador (Não utilizar expressões
>    regulares)
>    (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html
>    https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html)
> 2. Crie um programa em Java que solicita ao usuário um identificador e
>    apresenta se o que foi informado é um valor válido ou inválido.

Avancei até aqui com o código.

```
package semana04.exercicios;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Ex04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String codigo;
        char primeira, segunda, ultima;
        System.out.println("Digite seu código de funcionário: ");
        codigo = sc.nextLine();

        if (codigo.length() > 7 || codigo.length() < 7) {
            System.out.println("Código inválido.");
        } else {
            primeira = codigo.charAt(0);
            segunda = codigo.charAt(1);
            ultima = codigo.charAt(6);
            
            if(primeira != 'B' || segunda !='R' || ultima != 'X'){
                System.out.println("Código inválido.");
            }
            if(primeira == 'B' && segunda == 'R' && ultima == 'X'){
                System.out.println("O código é válido.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tenho 1 problema:

Não sei como realizar a verificação dos números do meio. Pois de acordo com o enunciado se inicia em 0001, logo, se o usuária digitasse 0000, por exemplo, o retorno teria que ser de código inválido. Mas ao digitar 0000 como números do meio, o retorno é de código válido. Quais linhas de código devo adicionar , e onde ?

Comment: Vou dar duas dicas, a função deve retornar um boolean (`true` ou `false`). E encadear booleanos com operadores booleanos também resulta em um booleano.

Answer (score 1):

Na minha opinião, a melhor forma de resolver esse exercício seria através de expressões regulares, mas o enunciado proíbe seu uso...

Aproveitando sua classe, sugiro algo assim:

```java
public class Ex04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Digite seu código de funcionário: ");
            final String codigo = sc.nextLine();

            if (codigo.length() != 7) {
                System.out.println("Código inválido.");
            } else if (!codigo.startsWith("BR") || !codigo.endsWith("X")) {
                System.out.println("Código inválido.");
            } else {
                final int val = Integer.parseInt(codigo, 2, 6, 10);

                if (val < 1 || val > 9999) {
                    System.out.println("Código inválido.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("O código é válido.");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Código inválido.");
        }
    }
}
```

Um par de comentários:

- Ao abrir um `Scanner`, você deve fechá-lo;
- O método `Integer.parseInt` pode lançar algumas exceções, é importante você capturá-las (inclusive, o código que envio pode ser melhorado nesse aspecto).

Comment: Vale lembrar que `Integer.parseInt(codigo, 2, 6, 10)` só funciona a partir do Java 9. E como [ainda tem muita gente usando Java 8](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3652408/java-8-still-dominates-but-java-17-wave-is-coming-survey.html), acho que vale o aviso :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Perfeito. Eu fiquei "despreocupado" em relação às versões do Java porque, no enunciado do exercício, os links de referência à documentação estão na versão 17.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode inserir mais um if dentro do seu último if, desta vez para verificar se os 4 caracteres do meio são iguais a '0', utilizando o and(&&) entre eles, nesse caso o código é inválido, no próximo else o código é válido.

```
codigo.charAt(2) == '0' && codigo.charAt(3) == '0' && codigo.charAt(4) == '0' && codigo.charAt(5) =='0'
```